# State of flag not getting reflected in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a HTML page which is linked to a controller in AngularJS. In controller I have a flag `showTree=true` . I am showing status of this flag in my HTML page using `<h3>{{showTree}}</h3>`

When I set `showTree=false` it gets reflected in HTML page, but When I change it back to `showTree=true` change is not getting reflected in the HTML page.

I checked state of the flag using

```
 $scope.$watch('showTree',function(){
            alert("changed"+$scope.showTree);
            console.log($scope.showTree);
        });
```

The results show that the value is getting changed. But still it is not getting reflected in the HTML page.

I tried using `$scope.$apply();`  it didn't work.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle with the code. There's not enough information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: From where you are changing value of showTree?

Comment: @Jay From another html page. Do you think using same controller for two different html pages might cause the problem?

Comment: So, you have two routes setup to use the same controller? Is that what I am understanding? If that is the case, then I can guarantee that is the problem.

Comment: Yes, if you are using ng-include then it may create problem because it creates new scope.

Comment: Yep, problem was initiating the same controller twice. Its fixed now, thank you all for the help

Comment: @JayShukla yes, that was the problem i used ng-include and linked the html file, I was calling the same controller from the included file as well.

Comment: @JayShukla can you put that comment in answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its `scope` problem. You might be using ng-include which creates new scope so when you are changing value of `$scope.showTree` it changes value but it creates new `showTree` in child scope and you expecting changes in parent scope. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. [I created a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/w2zjBDh0k2dbC9LHYHFX?p=preview) and it works for me. Can you get this plunkr to fail?

Answer (score 1):

Try using observe. You have just watched the field and put a log.

Have created a plunker. Just see if it helps.

http://plnkr.co/edit/DmQT0JD7FsTOupunLtuh?p=preview